# Is there a difference in the speed of the *generated code* between ASM and Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I am considering runtime byte-code generation/modification for a Java project.

Two important, and still maintained, APIs are ASM and Javassist.

ASM is the fastest at generating the code, and probably the most powerful. But it's also a lot less user-friendly than Javassist.

In my case, I want to perform the bytecode manipulation upfront, so that it is complete at the end of the application setup phase. So the speed of manipulation/generation is not critical. What is critical, is the speed of the generated code, because it will be part of a *real-time* desktop game, not the typical web-app, where the network delays hide the costs of reflection completely.

So my question is, does Javassist introduce some unnecessary overhead in the byte-code, which would not be present when using ASM? Or, expressed another way, is working at the ASM level going to provide me with a speed boost in the *generated code* compared to working with Javassist?

[EDIT] I'm interested in the newest version of both tools, and mostly interested to see if anyone tried them both on the same problem, and saw any significant difference in the speed of the resulting classes.

Comment: Try them both and micro benchmark the results.  Also, remember that the JIT can possibly skew "less efficient" byte code to make it more efficient in real life usage.

Comment: @KevinWelker That is kind of like saying: "Find the answer to your own question, and then tell us!" :D The main benefit of me asking, is so that I don't have to learn them both! If I wanted to, then of course I would do my own benchmarks, *instead of asking here*.

Comment: The premise of SO questioning is that you have looked for answers elsewhere and couldn't find them and/or you have tried something and didn't understand your results. I see evidence of neither.  And the main point of suggesting you try goes with my other point: there is no correct answer because the JIT will make results vary per individual situation, so you have to try it to know which will be faster.

Comment: I did look elsewhere, and saw no answer for it. I also do not know how you expect me to prove you that I search and did not find anything. Assuming that I did not search, without proof (like that a useful result comes up on the first few pages of Google), is insulting IMO. While I agree that the only way to really know is to try it myself, atm I am expecting at least one week of work to implement my solution with Javassist, and two with ASM. I think I am justified to ask if anyone else has some experience before spending 3 weeks so I can compare myself, instead of one.

Comment: Sorry you feel insulted -- I can understand that, though that was not my intention. My technical explanation about the JIT stands, and I don't see a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to provide a simple objective answer to this. It would (I imagine) depend on the versions of the respective tools, the nature of the code you are generating, and (most importantly) whether you are using the respective tools as well as they can be used.

The other thing you should consider is whether going down the byte-code manipulation route is likely to give you enough performance benefit to compensate for the increased software development and maintenance pain.  (And that can't be answered by anyone but yourself ...)

Anyway, my advice would be to only go down this route if you've already tried the "pure Java" approach and found it to give unacceptable performance.

Comment: +1 A "wise" answer, even if it does not actually answer the question. I would, of course, be using the most current version of those tools. And the code will go in a framework, so I write it once and forget about it. My problems can only be solved at runtime, since they involve a "runtime plugin system", so it cannot be solved by Java code at compile time.

Comment: @SebastienDiot - I'm puzzled by your last sentence.  Java supports runtime "plugins" just fine (using reflection) without the need to resort to bytecode manipulation.  What is special about your problem?

Comment: I'm writing a real-time 3D game, so response time has to be in ms. And my domain objects need to be able to "change type" at runtime, when they get upgraded/downgraded. It's possible with composition, but involves a large amount of boiler-plate, which I want to generate at runtime, because the game is plugin-based, and the plugins are developed independently by players. The player chooses from a plugin repository, and my framework must "merge" the chosen plugins together at runtime, because the total number of combinations will be exponential, preventing merge in the repository.

Comment: Well, despite what you've said, I think that there is a major risk of you expending major effort on an optimization that either is 1) not necessary at all, or 2) won't help (because you are optimizing the wrong thing), or 3) could be done just as well by careful design in pure Java.  I would advise implementing in pure Java FIRST ... and using profiling to decide what is most in need of optimization.  Then decide what to do about it.  Maybe you trust your intuition more than a profiler.  In your position, I wouldn't.

Comment: I am doing the manual solution first, but only so I know how to do it automatically later. The problem is that one way or another, I need glue code that binds the different plugins together, as they might be augmenting *the same objects*. The only fully generic way I found so far would be to use one object *per field and per method*; the entities become two maps. That would be much too expensive. I have spent weeks looking for some API; there is nothing fine-grained like that. In short the glue code binds code that did not know of each other at compile time, so it cannot be done "manually".